# How can I generate zip file without saving to the disk with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, zip

I have generated many PDF files in memory and I want to compress them into one zip file before sending it as a email attachment. I have looked at Rubyzip and it does not allows me to create a zip file without saving it to disk (maybe I am wrong).

Is there any way I can compress those file without creating a temp file?

Comment: See [the answer by @vas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9712252/244128), it does exactly what you want!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had a similar problem which I solved using the rubyzip gem and the stringio object.
It turns out that rubyzip provides a method that returns a stringio object: `ZipOutputStream.write_buffer`.

You can create the zip file structure as you like using `put_next_entry` and write and once you are finished you can rewind the stringio and read the binary data using sysread.

See the following simple example (works for rubyzip 0.9.X)

```rb
require 'zip/zip'
stringio = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zio|
  zio.put_next_entry("test.txt")
  zio.write "Hello world!"
end
stringio.rewind
binary_data = stringio.sysread
```

Tested on jruby 1.6.5.1 (ruby-1.9.2-p136) (2011-12-27 1bf37c2) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_29) [Windows Server 2008-amd64-java])

The following example works for rubyzip >= 1.0.0

```rb
require 'rubygems'    
require 'zip'
stringio = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zio|
  zio.put_next_entry("test.txt")
  zio.write "Hello world!"
end
binary_data = stringio.string
```

Tested on jruby 1.7.22 (1.9.3p551) 2015-08-20 c28f492 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_79-b14 +jit [linux-amd64] and rubyzip gem 1.1.7

Comment: Thanks, it works. However at the time that I wrote the question, the method was not existing yet. It was added in 2011-01-07. Thanks for your answer and next time that I need to zip in memory, I will know how.

Comment: LoadError cannot load such file -- zip

Comment: Above works with older versions of rubyzip gem. Version 1.0 changed the interface. Please see: https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#important-note

Comment: write_buffer is now Zip::OutputStream::write_buffer

Comment: Also, noticed that with the newer version require 'zip/zip' does not work. require 'zip' is the correct statement.

Comment: OMG `stringio.string` was exactly what i was missing. Thank you for this.

Comment: This example works! Tested withe Ruby 2.6.6! +1 :-)

Comment: Hello, can anyone help, I'm unable to make this code work :( 
I'm trying to put a file from S3 inside the zip, but it does not work

`
s3_file = s3_client.get_object(bucket: bucket_name, key: s3_filename)
file = s3_file.body
stringio = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zio|
  zio.put_next_entry("test1.zip")
  zf = Zip::File.new(file, create: true, buffer: true)
  zio.write(file)
end
`
I get the following error message
`TypeError (no implicit conversion of StringIO into String)`

Answer (score 5):

Ruby comes with a very convenient `StringIO` library - this can be used for using a String as output IO object or faking reading a file backed by a String.

The challenge here is that RubyZip does not support directly taking an IO object when creating a `Zip::ZipOutputStream`, but if you look at the implementation of the `initialize`, and depending on your willingness to experiment, you may be able to extend the class and allow it to take either an IO object or a file name in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two RubyZip libraries that I was able to find.

1. [Chilkat's Ruby Zip Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ruby-zip.asp)
2. [rubyzip on Sourceforge](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/)

Chilkat's library definitely allows one to create a zip file in memory instead of writing it to disk automatically as seen in these links: [Zip to Memory](http://www.example-code.com/ruby/ruby-zip-to-memory.asp), [Zip from in memory data](http://www.example-code.com/ruby/ruby-zip-from-memory.asp)

The one on SourceForge, on the other hand, may provide an option of zipping a file in memory but I'm not entirely certain since I'm very new to ruby. The SourceForge rubyzip is based on `java.util.zip` which has led to it having a class called [`ZipOutputStream`](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipOutputStream.html). I don't know how good the rubyzip implementation is, but with `java.util.zip` implementation the [`OutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) can be set to `ByteArrayOutputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, `FilterOutputStream`, `ObjectOutputStream`, `OutputStream`, `PipedOutputStream`....

If that holds true for the rubyzip implementation then it should be a matter of using `ZipOutputStream` to pass in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` of sorts which would result in it being output to memory.

If it doesn't exist in rubyzip, then I'm sure you could always write your own implementation and submit it for inclusion in rubyzip seeing as it is opensource.

Comment: The one I was referring was the gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip

I don't want to use the Chilkat library since there it's not open source.

Comment: I won't downrate this, but I didn't find anywhere a comment like "no, the standard Ruby ZIP classes can NOT do this". I believe you should have started with it.

Comment: In fact the ZipOutputStream new method takes a file name as argument, I didn't find any way to pass an IO object.

Comment: dimitko, there are no standard ruby library for zip. I have checked rubyzip but it seems that there is nothing for doing what I want.

Comment: @flutedemetan, like I said above, if it doesn't exist then you'll either need to use another library or make your own addition to the rubyzip open source project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, and depending upon how much RAM you have, and how large your files are, you could always use tmpfs (shared memory).  Then, the rubyzip disk-based methods will work.  http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt

Comment: Mounting requires superuser permissions

Comment: @AbeVoelker yes, this answer assumes that you already have a tmpfs, or have a friendly local sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works well but it didn't solve my problem.  I didn't want to use the [write_buffer method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyzip/rubyzip/Zip/OutputStream#write_buffer-class_method) because it automatically closes the stream after the block closes.  The code snippet below gives you more control over when the stream is created and closed.

```rb
require 'stringio'
require 'zip'

io = StringIO.new
zip_io = Zip::OutputStream.new(io, true) # 'true' indicates 'io' is a stream
zip_io.put_next_entry('test.txt')
zip_io.write('Hello world!')

# Read the data and close the streams
io.rewind
binary_data = io.read
zip_io.close_buffer
io.close
```