# Zip a string in memory Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to zip a string (either with a gem or standard lib) so that I can get the zipped result of a string? Example:

```
"hello world".zip #=> zipped version of string
```

Also, decompression would be nice if someone could include that in their solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate zip file without saving to the disk with Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405921/how-can-i-generate-zip-file-without-saving-to-the-disk-with-ruby)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Zlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html)

```
>> require 'zlib'
=> true
>> s = "this is a long string with many many many many repetition"
=> "this is a long string with many many many many repetition"
>> s.size
=> 57
>> cs = Zlib.deflate(s)
=> "x\x9C+\xC9\xC8,V\x00\xA2D\x85\x9C\xFC\xBCt\x85\xE2\x92\xA2L U\x9EY\x92\xA1\x90\x9B\x98W\x89N\x14\xA5\x16\xA4\x96d\x96d\xE6\xE7\x01\x00\\?\x15P"
>> cs.size
=> 48
>> is = Zlib.inflate(cs)
=> "this is a long string with many many many many repetition"
```

Comment: Was just about to post that, as it's in stdlib, so very accessible :) http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/Deflate.html

Comment: Thanks! The other solution had me write out to the file. ZLIB docs aren't exactly the best.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to refer you to this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9712252/1419586) by [vas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916791/vas), it details the [rubyzip gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip), which, as you can see in the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rubyzip/0.9.8/frames) has input and outputstream objects  and should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Then flag/vote to close as duplicate instead of posting a link to another question/answer.

Comment: I did flag as duplicate as well, but I don't know how it will be merged or closed so I wasn't sure wether OP would then see the link. Sorry I'm very new to SO. :)

Comment: You can always post a comment in that case.