# Receive file from server in Chrome extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to connect my Chrome Extension to be able to download a file from my Ruby on Rails server. In particular, when the user clicks a button on the extension, the extension should send an AJAX request to the server, and then the server should send a file `file.zip` back to the user.

How would the server send a file back to the extension of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Rails side, make sure the returned `Content-Type` header is `application/zip`. You can use `#send_file` or `#send_data` to send zip file to client. See [ActionController::DataStreaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html)

Use `#send_file`

```
send_file '/path/to.zip', :type => 'application/zip'
```

Or use `#send_data`

```
zip_data = generate_zip_data()
send_data zip_data, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => 'data.zip'
```

For generating dynamic zip file, see other topics:

- [How can I generate zip file without saving to the disk with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405921/how-can-i-generate-zip-file-without-saving-to-the-disk-with-ruby)

On google chrome extension, you might want to create new tab with the zip file url. That causes browser downloads file.

```
function buttonClickHandler() {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "the url to zip file"}, function() {});
}
```