# How can I create a zip file without temporary files in ruby?

Tags: ruby, zip, temporary-files

I create a zip file with some generated content (in other words: the files in the archive don't exist, the content is build in my script).

I use a script similar to this:

```
#~ gem 'rubyzip', '=1.1.0'
require 'zip/zip'

zipname = 'test.zip'
File.delete(zipname) if File.exists?(zipname) #delete previous version

Zip::ZipFile.open(zipname, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  1.upto(100) do |i| #Just some testfiles with content
    zipfile.get_output_stream("%08i.txt" % i) do |output_entry_stream| #Filename
          output_entry_stream.write("Testcontent %08i" % i)            #generated content
        end
      sleep 1  #sleep some time to see the temporary files
  end   #testdocs
end #ZipFile.open(zipname)
```

This works fine, I get my zip with the correct data inside.

But during the zip creation I have a lot of temporary files. They are deleted when the zip is finished, but the files disturb me during the creation. And if the process raises an exception, then I have to delete them manual.

I have this behaviour with Zip::VERSION 2.0.2 and 1.1.0 (using the gem rubyzip)

- Can I avoid this temporary files?
- If not: Can I determine a (temporary) folder for them?

Comment: this might help you: http://info.michael-simons.eu/2008/01/21/using-rubyzip-to-create-zip-files-on-the-fly/

Comment: "the files disturb me during the creation." You do understand that your OS creates files constantly, and cleans them up, as do the majority of applications you use? Does that behavior disturb you? Handle the exceptions you encounter and Ruby will be able to clean up after itself also. *Not* using the temporary files will result in code that isn't scalable, as it's easy to imagine trying to create a file larger than available RAM.

Comment: @UriAgassi My problem is not the zip-file (I need that file later in my target directory), but the files I want to add to them.

Comment: @theTinMan I generate my zip and during the runtime I continue to work in the same directory. So I didn't want to have a lot new files. Sure, I could use another working directory and copy the result. But I thought there should be a "only memory" solution. With peters solution I need now 1/3 less time - a side effect I hoped for ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the answer at "[How can I generate zip file without saving to the disk with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405921/how-can-i-generate-zip-file-without-saving-to-the-disk-with-ruby?rq=1)"

I adapted your example to demonstrate it works.

```
require 'zip/zip'

zipname = 'test.zip'
File.delete(zipname) if File.exists?(zipname) #delete previous version

stringio = Zip::ZipOutputStream::write_buffer do |zio|
  1.upto(5) do |i| #Just some testfiles with content
    zio.put_next_entry("test#{i}.txt") #Filename
    zio.write("Testcontent %08i" % i)  #generated content
    sleep 1 #sleep some time to see the temporary files
  end
end
stringio.rewind #reposition buffer pointer to the beginning
File.new("test.zip","wb").write(stringio.sysread) #write buffer to zipfile
```

Comment: I already found the answer you posted, but my problem was not the zip file itself, but the files I add. When I test your code, there are no temporary files. So it seems this is also the solution of my problem. I had it before my eyes, but didn't identify it as the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution. It works (after I updated rubyzip on my productive environment).

Comment: One hint: If the generated contents is in binary fromat, then you shoudl use `File.new("test.zip","wb")` (mode wb for binary, not w).

Comment: You forgot to mention that the Gem required is `zip-zip`

Answer (score 6):

Do you need zip compatibility, or is gzip sufficient? Ruby comes with [the Zlib module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html), which makes it easy to read/write gzip compressed files using [Zlib::GzipWriter](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipReader.html) and [Zlib::GzipWriter](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html) respectively:

```
require 'zlib'
Zlib::GzipWriter.open('foobar.gz') do |fo|
  fo.write "how now brown cow\n"
end
```

At the command-line:

```
$file foobar.gz
foobar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri May 30 08:56:58 2014
$gunzip foobar.gz
$cat foobar
how now brown cow
```

If you need to create archives containing multiple files, Ruby's [Archive::Tar](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/archive-tar-0.9.0/Archive/Tar.html) class can help. tar.gz files are smaller than the equivalent .zip files [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format) due to differences in how Zip and tar -> gZip work.

Be very careful trying to buffer in memory when tarring or compressing files. It's easy to test in development because we rarely use full-size files, but once code hits production, and the file sizes balloon to astronomical sizes, all of a sudden your system can run into a memory crunch. We routinely deal with files well into the GB-range, and trying to compress those in memory would make an app a bad citizen on a production server. *I* don't like getting calls late at night just to hear something I wrote was causing problems, so be conservative and sure that your application can handle its task without failures.

Comment: I have approx. 30000 files in a 30-40MB zip. I tried peters solution and it works. And I don't expects calls, up to now I generate the zips once and then they are reused.