# Rubyzip download attachments without creating the archive

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4, archive, rubyzip

I am using `rubyzip` with `rails 4` and I am trying to make a custom method to download all the attachments in the submission table without phisically creating the zip file.

`submissions_controller.rb`

```
  def download
    @submissions = Submission.all

    file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/archive.zip"

    Zip::ZipFile.open(file, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      @submissions.each do |filename|
       zipfile.add(file, filename.file.url(:original, false))
      end
    end
   zip_data = File.read(file)
   send_data(zip_data, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "All submissions")
  end
```

How can I set the file var right. The documentation says that that is the archive name, but I do not want to create that physical archive. Maybe just as a tmp ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405921/how-can-i-generate-zip-file-without-saving-to-the-disk-with-ruby

Comment: Make a tmp file and send it, what's the problem?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do this

Comment: The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) can help you. Also try to search something, you not a first dev who make feature like this.

Comment: Please see my updated comment. I am trying to create that file and send it as an attachment, I get a no access error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right syntax that made my code work 100% fine:

```
# Download zip file of all submission
  def download
    @submissions = Submission.all

    archiveFolder = Rails.root.join('tmp/archive.zip') #Location to save the zip

    # Delte .zip folder if it's already there
    FileUtils.rm_rf(archiveFolder)

    # Open the zipfile
    Zip::ZipFile.open(archiveFolder, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      @submissions.each do |filename|
        zipfile.add(filename.file_file_name, 'public/files/submissions/files/' + filename.id.to_s + '/original/' + filename.file_file_name)
      end
    end

    # Send the archive as an attachment
    send_file(archiveFolder, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => '2016 Submissions.zip', :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code:

```
def download
  @submissions = Submission.all

  file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/archive.zip"

  Zip::ZipFile.open(file, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    @submissions.each do |filename|
      zipfile.add(file, filename.file.url(:original, false))
    end
  end
  send_file(file, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "All submissions")
end
```

You should use `send_file` not `send_data`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am though still getting the access error `Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - `

Comment: You should check the folder, and look if file persisted it the `tmp` directory.

Comment: I changed it to just `/tmp/archive.zip`. The folder is there, but I get a not found error -> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/archive.zip20161124-11560-1wprn6o. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: folder there, what about file? Also when you get this error? `Permission denied` while zipping or send?

Comment: So I have my files under my `public/system` folder and I want them to go into `tmp/archive.zip` and get sent to the user, and get erased from there

Comment: @VladBalanescu please read my comments and give me the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128933/discussion-between-vlad-balanescu-and-).